# Would replacing a 35 Ah battery with a 100 Ah battery damage the alternator?

Tags: battery-charging, alternator

I have an Elemax SH7600ex generator that came with a 35 Ah battery for the electric start system. That battery has died, and I've replaced it with a 100 Ah battery that I had lying around.

The generator has been working/starting fine for a month, and I know that the cranking motor won't be damaged by the higher capacity battery, but is there a chance that I'm overloading and gradually damaging the alternator of the generator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your generator has a "proper" charging circuit with regulator, there shouldn't be any problem in most circumstances.  The charger will simply charge the new battery as normal.

However, there is one circumstance you should consider.

That is: what happens if the generator won't start?  The original battery is *probably* sized such that if someone keeps trying to start the generator continuously, the battery will die *before* the starting motor is ruined from overheating.

The larger battery allows someone to keep trying to start the generator for longer than the starter can handle and can thus damage or destroy it.

This isn't a problem so long as you are aware of it.  If your generator has automatic start, ensure that there is a timer that limits cranking time.  If you are starting the generator manually and it doesn't start right away, make sure that you stop cranking before you wreck the starter motor.

My father ran a service station while I was growing up and I saw firsthand what happens to starters that have been overheated.  I even learned to to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

If **everything else** on the battery is same as the old one, except it's capacity, it will not damage the alternator. 
Similar questions to this one have been asked in the past, make sure you read them too.

Comment: That is not generally true. I think that a design engineer can size the charging circuit assuming it would not be on for more time than the time needed to fully charge a 35Ah battery. Now probably said circuit is a diode, but you never know... If the thing has been running for a month it does not mean it can still fail. I suggest OP to pay attention if for some reason the battery gets very depleted, maybe charge it in some other way just to be 100.1% sure.

Comment: The OP needs to provide more information about the question.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: The charging duty cycle is irrelevant. The difference between charging a 35 Ah battery vs. a 100 Ah battery is down in the noise, well within the overall design margins of the charging system.

Comment: What I meant is that if the charging circuit is poorly designed the chances for it to fail are higher if it stays on for a longer time. Like if that's just a diode rated for a max current that barely is enough, then charging a 100Ah battery can actually broke it because of heating (sorry for the poor explaination) you might be implying that the charging circuit powers a load of thing then it is oversized?

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Trust me, automotive system designers are *very* sensitive to costs, but that includes *all* costs over the lifetime of the car, including both the cost of materials to build it and the cost of parts and labor to service it (especially under warranty). They do not trim the design margins so tightly that the difference between charging time for a 35 Ah battery vs. a 100 Ah battery will break the charging system -- if it did, they would be replacing the charging system far too often for other reasons.

Comment: I do trust you @DaveTweed I just think that adding that bit might be useful. The generator (that's not a car after all) might be crappy or whatever... Anyway we have common ground on "that might happen if *very* bad design methods are used" don't we? I thought that what I was saying was just plain impossible instead it's very very unlikely, right?

Comment: @VladimirCravero: The current through the rectifier diodes is limited by the alternator. Battery short cut is a very plausible failure scenario, so a sensible designer will either add a fuse, or just use diodes/cables that can withstand the highest possible current the alternator is able to provide (unless he wants to set the car on fire).

Comment: @Triak Thanks for your answer. I've tried searching around for questions like these, but didn't come across any that specifically addressed the alternator.

Comment: @RolandMieslinger "battery short is  a very plausible failure scenario" really? I wouldn't think that... Can you please elaborate that a bit? ty